# Is there any standard for the input impedance of an audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio

Ebay and other stores are full of items like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HXJ8002-DC-2-0-5-5V-3W-Audio-Amplifier-Power-Supply-Board-New/192002720286?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649). 
These are audio amplifiers for various uses and output impedance. But for almost none of them, I was able to find any specification regarding the input impedance. I suspect there is something to know about that: is there any standard input impedance for audio amplifiers? at least sufficiently probable for taking the risk to buy such an item?

Comment: 1Kohm to 10Kohm are typical ranges the prior stage (RIAA preamps, etc) promise to drive without distortion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level      Typically anything above 10k Ohm input impedance would be considered fine.

Comment: *if* it would have too low input impedance, then you could solve that by just putting an [op-amp in buffer configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Op-amp_implementation) between your source and the audio amplifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a sortof standard for a certain class of professional audio gear.  This standard is 600 Ω.  All "line level" audio in such a setup is expected to drive 600 Ω.  This is also the impedance of the microphones.

However, many many amps don't follow this.  In fact, most amps try to be "high", which means to not appreciably load the output stage of whatever they think is producing the signal.  Of course everyone's idea of "high" is different.  The most common is probably around 10 kΩ.

That's what I've done with audio gear aimed at consumers.  Anything that produces a consumer audio signal won't be damaged, loaded to the point of distortion, or even appreciably attenuated by 10 kΩ.  Otherwise, you want the input impedance to be as low as possible avoid picking up stray noise when nothing is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the input impedance to an audio amplifier is 'high'. That is, high enough to be driven comfortably by any audio source output. But of course, without a proper specification, you are taking something of a gamble.

10k to 100k is the usual sort of range we find, though some can be less. Even something as low as 1k will be driven easily by most op-amps outputs, whether they're designed to drive headphones (many are) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Buying one is a gamble. No spec = no data beyond reverse engineering the photos, which can be fake.

Your example seem to be based on IC type HXJ8002. Input impedance is dependent on used resistors, in this case there's a resistor just like in the input of inverting amplifier made of an opamp. That resistor = the input impedance. The gain also depends on it. With extreme good luck the input impedance can be 20kOhm.  (=component value in the example application circuit). But as well it can be only 2kOhm. See the datasheet of the used IC:

http://www.shenzhensum.com/products/datasheet/8002(2.0W).pdf

If you can do SMD soldering, you can easily change the resistors and even it's possible to change the configuration to non-inverting. But then you should as well be able to build exactly, what you need. Consider to do it.

Comment: thx, very useful answer.